# Stop drag touch using hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3

How to stop touch or mouse drag-event using hitTestObject?

Like, while dragging the object1 and then hits object2. Drag-event should stop when object1 hits object2.

Why it does not stop-drag analog when a stone hits player?

onGame:

```
control:Controller = new Controller();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

private function loop (e:Event):void {
  if(player.hitTestObject(stone) {
    Controller.btn = 1;
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
public static var btn:Number;

analog.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, pressed);
analog.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, moving);
analog.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, unpress);

private function pressed(e:TouchEvent):void {
  btn = 0;
  analog.startTouchDrag(e:touchPointID);
}

private function moving(e:TouchEvent):void {
  if(btn == 1) {
     analog.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
  {
}
private function unpress(e:TouchEvent):void {
  analog.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
  btn = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this, here's a very quick and dirty way to do it:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

object1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onTouch);
object1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);
object1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onRelease);

function onTouch(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    object1.startDrag();
}

function onRelease(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    object1.stopDrag();
}

function onMove(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(object1.hitTestObject(object2))
    {
        object1.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

EDIT: in response to your comment, you can try this code (though it's untested)

```
import flash.events.TouchEvent;

object1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouch);
object1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onMove);
object1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onRelease);

function onTouch(e:TouchEvent):void 
{
    object1.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}
function onRelease(e:TouchEvent):void 
{
    object1.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}

function onMove(e:TouchEvent):void 
{
    if(object1.hitTestObject(object2))
    {
        object1.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just learn that using a device, the code should be in touch event for multitouch purpose, how it is on TouchEvent? Sorry, I'm still learning.

Comment: I updated the answer, but like I say above, it's untested as I don't have a device to test it on.